# CSRF Referer checking failed Django 1.8

Tags: csrf, django-1.8

I have searched about this but could not find any workable solution.

I have a website like www.example.com and subdomains a.example.com and b.example.com. When I try to post a request from a.example.com to b.example.com I get the error of Referer checking failed.

I have following settings in a.example.com and b.example.com:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".example.com"
```

But I am not able to make use of `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.8 has [strict referer checking](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/middleware/csrf.py#L160) for HTTPS. You cannot post from a.example.com to b.example.com with CSRF protection enabled in Django 1.8.

With Django 1.9 they added [CSRF trusted origins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins).